# C programming: Input is assigned but output display shows the incorrect value

Tags: c, scanf, var

I have been trying to figure out why my code isn't working properly. I know my code below is a mess (I am a rather poor C programmer thus far). Its a work in progress. Specifically

```
    printf("Please enter the index of the contact you wish to view. \nThis should be a positive integer\n\n");
    scanf("%d", &vIndex);
    fgetc(stdin);
    printf("The value of vIndex is %d", &vIndex);
```

I find that when i run my program I might select a keyboard input of 1, meaning I am looking at my second record in my file entries.txt. The printout of vIndex however is a number much much larger, much likely the last information stored there. Running in debug however, i find that vIndex change to 1 and but prints the strange number. My entire code is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct rec
{
    int i;
    float PI;
    char A;
} Record;

typedef struct
{
    char fname[20];
    char lname[50];
    char phone[15];
} Contact;


Record * arrayAlloc(int size);
char * stringAlloc(int size);
Contact * contactAlloc();
void structAlloc();

int main(void)
{

    int *ptrInt;
    Record * ptrRec;
    int i = 0;
    char * myName;
    Contact * contacts;
    ptrInt = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    int vIndex=0;
    int displayMenu();
    Contact * contactAlloc();
 //   void searchIndex();
    void searchFirst();
    void searchLast();
    void searchPhone();



    contacts = contactAlloc();
    char choice;
    choice = displayMenu();

    while (choice !=5)\
    {
        if (choice == 1)
         //   searchIndex();

            {
            printf("Please enter the index of the contact you wish to view. \nThis should be a positive integer\n\n");
    //        fgets(vIndex, 700, stdin);
            scanf("%d", &vIndex);
            fgetc(stdin);
            printf("The value of vIndex is %d", &vIndex);
            printf("You have selected to view the %d contact.\nFirst name:\t%c. \nLast Name:\t%c. \nPhone Number:\t%c.\n\n ", &vIndex, contacts[vIndex].fname, contacts[vIndex].lname, contacts[vIndex].phone);
            }

        else if (choice == 2)
            searchFirst();
        else if (choice == 3)
            searchLast();
        else if (choice == 4)
            searchPhone();
        choice = displayMenu();
    }
    printf("Thank for you using this program.\n");
    return 0;
}

int displayMenu()
{

    int choice = 0;
    while (choice!= 1 && choice != 2 && choice != 3 && choice != 4 && choice!=5)
    {
        printf("\nWelcome to the phone book application. Please choose from the following options:");
        printf("\n\n\t 1) Search the phone book by index. \n\t 2) Search the phone book by first name. \n\t 3) Search the phone book by last name. \n\t 4) Search the phone book by phone number. \n\t 5) Quit.\n\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
    }
    return choice;
}


Contact * contactAlloc()
{
   FILE * fin;
    int count = 0, i = 0;
    char aLine[100];
    Contact * ptrContact;

    fin = fopen("entries.txt", "r");
    if (fin != NULL)
    {
        while( fgets(aLine, sizeof(aLine), fin) != NULL )
        {
            count++;
        }

        fseek(fin, 0L, SEEK_SET);
        count = count / 3;

        ptrContact = (Contact *) calloc(count, sizeof(Contact));
        count = 0;

        while( fgets(aLine, sizeof(aLine), fin) != NULL )
        {
            if (aLine[strlen(aLine) - 1] == '\n')
            {
                aLine[strlen(aLine) - 1] = '\0';
            }

            if (i % 3 == 0)
            {
                strcpy(ptrContact[count].lname, aLine);
            }
            else if (i % 3 == 1)
            {
                strcpy(ptrContact[count].fname, aLine);
            }
            else if (i % 3 == 2)
            {
                strcpy(ptrContact[count].phone, aLine);
                //printf("Line %d at count %d: %s\n", i, count, aLine);
                count++;
            }
            i++;
        }
        //count=count*3;
        printf("%d contacts loaded.\n\n", count);
        fclose(fin);
    }
    return ptrContact;
}


/*
void searchIndex()
{
    int vIndex=0;
    printf("Please enter the index of the contact you wish to view. This should be a positive integer");
    scanf("%d", &vIndex);
    fgetc(stdin);
    printf("You have selected to view the %d contact.\nFirst name:\t%c. \nLast Name:\t%c. Phone Number:\t%c.\n\n ", &vIndex, &Contact[vIndex].fname, &Contact[vIndex].lname, &Contact[vIndex].phone);
}

*/
void searchFirst()
{


}

void searchLast()
{



}

void searchPhone()
{


}
```

Comment: Do you have some sample data to test this with?

Comment: You shouldn't be using the address-of operator in the `printf`. You don't want to pass the address of `vIndex` (which is what is printing), but the value.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the address of `vIndex` instead of the value:

```
printf("The value of vIndex is %d", &vIndex);
```

Change this line to the following:

```
printf("The value of vIndex is %d", vIndex);
```

Comment: I saw this _all the time_ as an intro CS course TA. Either they both `scanf()`/`printf()` using the variable value, or they both  `scanf()`/`printf()` using the variable address. There is so much confusion with this stuff.

Comment: @DavidFrye Generally, families of functions should be consistent to avoid such errors.

Comment: It certainly seems like it would help newbies avoid common errors, but it also sort of forces them to confront their lack of understanding about the difference between values and their addresses. It's a bit of a trap, but it's not without its benefits.